# How can I disable vectorization while using GCC?

Tags: gcc, vectorization, sse, simd, auto-vectorization

I am compiling my code using following command:

```
gcc -O3 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=6 -msse4.1 -ffast-math
```

With this all the optimizations are enabled.

But I want to disable vectorization while keeping the other optimizations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of the GCC switches can be used with a  `no` prefix to disable their behavior. Try with `-fno-tree-vectorize` (after `-O3` on the command line).

Comment: I tried this and still found xmm0 register in my code and calls to __ieee754_exp_avx. @Mat ? any help is welcome.

Comment: @Hugo, you have to differentiate between auto-vectorization and the usage of SIMD instructions. You can try `-mno-sse`, `-mno-avx` and similar options to tell the compiler avoid emitting any SIMD code.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: note that x86-64 uses XMM registers as part of the calling convention for scalar float / double.  With `-mno-sse` you'd need to totally avoid any FP math (at least in function call / return).  For kernel code or something, avoiding any FP math is generally sufficient to avoid any x87 instructions *within* functions, and GCC doesn't auto-vectorize with MMX instructions even when SSE2 isn't available, so you generally don't need `-mno-mmx`.

Answer (score 9):

you can also selectively enable and disable vectorization with the optimize function attributes or pragmas

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html

e.g.

```
__attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))
void f(double * restrict a, double * restrict b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        a[i] += b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excellent, now that gcc has become more aggressive at vectorizing e.g.

```
extern "C" __attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))
/* Subroutine */
int s111_ (integer * ntimes, integer * ld, integer * n,
           real * ctime, real * dtime,
           real * __restrict a, real * b, real * c__, real * d__,
           real * e, real * aa, real * bb, real * cc)
{
    ....
    for (i__ = 2; i__ <= i__2; i__ += 2)
        a[i__] = a[i__ - 1] + b[i__];
    ....
```

In the case posted above, removing `restrict` used to do the job, but now g++ 6.0 can't be stopped from vectorizing by removing `__restrict`.