# Can I enable vectorization only for one part of the code?

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, pragma

Is there a way to enable vectorization only for some part of the code, like a pragma directive? Basically having as if the -ftree-vectorize is enabled only while compiling some part of the code? [Pragma simd](https://www.cilkplus.org/tutorial-pragma-simd) for example is not available with gcc...

The reason is that from benchmarking we saw that with -O3 (which enables vectorization) the timings were worse than with -O2. But there are some part of the code for which we would like the compiler to try vectorizing loops.

One solution I could use would be to restrict the compiler directive to one file.

Comment: Typically vectorization should *speed up* your code, **if** it has been applied. Are you sure of that? How did you find out it slowed down the code?

Comment: @black We are speaking about a big project, where there's, however, not so much to vectorize. -O3 introduces some overhead that can in some cases generate slower code http://stackoverflow.com/a/19985801/2436175. It was the case in our timing benchmarking. Turning on tree-vectorize globally has the same risk, while I am in the situation to guess very well which part of code it would be worth to ask to the compiler to vectorize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can either disable it for the whole module or [individual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778174/how-can-i-disable-vectorization-while-using-gcc) functions. [You can't however do this for particular loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696323/disable-auto-vectorization-of-specific-loops-in-a-function-in-gcc).

For individual functions use 
`__attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))`.

For whole modules `-O3` automatic enables `-ftree-vectorize`. I'm not sure how to disable it once it's enabled but you can use `-O2` instead. If you want to use all of `-O3` except `-ftree-vectorize` then do this

```
gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers > /tmp/O3-opts
gcc -c -Q -O2 --help=optimizers > /tmp/O2-opts
diff /tmp/O2-opts /tmp/O3-opts | grep enabled
```

And then include all the options except for `-ftree-vectorize`.

Edit: I don't see `-fno-tree-vectorize` in the man pages but it works anyway so you can do `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize`.

**Edit:** The OP actually wants to enable vectorization for particular functions or whole modules. In that case for individual functions `__attribute__((optimize("tree-vectorize")))` can be used and for whole modules `-O2 -ftree-vectorize`.

**Edit (from Antonio):** In theory there is a pragma directive to enable tree-vectorizing all functions that follow

```
#pragma GCC optimize("tree-vectorize")
```

But it seems not to work with my g++ compiler, maybe because of the bug mentioned here:
[How to enable optimization in G++ with #pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321149/how-to-enable-optimization-in-g-with-pragma). On the other hand, the function attribute works.

Comment: Thanks! I was reading about "attribute" exactly now :) BTW, I did not explain myself very clearly: we would like to stay with -O2, and enable vectorization locally (on some files, or on some functions).

Comment: @Antonio, actually you were clear. It's my fault, I read your question wrong. I think you can use `__attribute__((optimize("tree-vectorize")))` or `-O2 -ftree-vectorize` for whole modules.

Comment: @Antonio, I'm slightly confused by your request to enable vectorizing all functions. You say `#pragma GCC optimize("tree-vectorize")` does not work but what's wrong with `-ftree-vectorize`. Shouldn’t that do what you want?

Comment: I am working in a project where adding a specific flag for only one file would be difficult. So, if it was the file itself that made this request it would be better.

Comment: @Antonio, oh, I understand. I'm glad that `__attribute__((optimize("tree-vectorize")))` still works then.